# Соединение двух баз с помощью EF. Приложение WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, linq

Можете подсказать, у меня есть две таблицы userFromAUFsи userOtpusks и я их объединяю так:

```
            var additem = from u in context.userFromAUFs
                          join b in context.userOtpusks on u.FirstName equals 
                          b.FirstNameO
                          select u;
```

Далее additem заношу в ObservableCollection:

```
fromAUF = new ObservableCollection<UserFromAUF>(additem);
```

в ListBox делаю Binding. Все работает, список выводит, но не весь, а только то, что находится в первой таблице. ListBoxItem изменен через стили, в стиле Binding всем полям проставлен.

Если делаю так:

```
        var additem = from u in context.userFromAUFs
                      join b in context.userOtpusks on u.FirstName equals b.FirstNameO
                      select new
                      {
                          name = u.FirstName,
                          dolznost = u.Dolznost
                      };
```

выходит ошибка

```
Ошибка  CS1503  Аргумент 1: не удается преобразовать из "System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous type: string name, string dolznost>>" в "System.Collections.Generic.List<MVVM.Data.UserFromAUF>".
```

Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Соединение двух _баз_ или двух _таблиц_?

Comment: Alexander Petrov, таблиц

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/534794/3129992